Movie about 3 men invading a rich man's house up in the hill ended up hostaging two daughters
From what I can remember, it was about 3 men (or more) planning to invade a rich man's house up in the hill. It was fully secured so they waited for the man to leave the house but his two daughters were left there. Also, I remember the room with the fiber glass that made it hard for the suspect to get the victims and there's like a waterfall display inside the house. The main culprit is like a psychopath but I think he fell for the older girl and there was a scene where he tied the girl to a chair and I think he was trying to kiss her. At the end of the movie he was like caught on fire. He has long hair. I really really want to see that movie again! Please help me. Tia!

The plot, you described, is similar to a plot of the movie Hostage with Bruce Willis.
Similarities:

isolated house up in a hill,
three teenage attackers, one of them is a psychopath with long hair,
rich father with two kids, the eldest being a girl,
panic room, difficult to get into,
the house ends up on fire at the end of the movie.

Differences:

the father never leaves the house,
younger kid is a boy.


Omg that's it! Thank you so much! I've been searching for the title of that movie for so long! I forgot because it was like 5 or more years since I have watched it. Thank you!
